# TextInputLayout ellipsize options

Tags: android, material-components-android

I have a dropdown made with TextInputLayout and AutoCompleteTextView, when I select a value from the dropdown, it shows the last half of text in container, like if I select "John Doe Company", it will show "oe Company", I want to show first half "John Do..." or something like that, is there anyway we can do it?

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/select_item_given"           
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.ExposedDropdownMenu"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="54dp"
    android:layout_marginHorizontal="24dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
    android:hint="@string/select"
    android:textColorHint="@color/hint"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/items_given"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

                <AutoCompleteTextView
                    android:id="@+id/items_given_selection"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:ellipsize="end"
                    android:focusable="false"
                    android:maxLines="1" />

      
</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add in your AutoCompleteTextView the attributes **android:inputType="none"** and **android:singleLine="true"** it should solve your issue like below:

```
<AutoCompleteTextView
    android:id="@+id/items_given_selection"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:inputType="none"
    android:singleLine="true"/>
```